# Get OSSEC syscheck to alert on change to directory but not its contents

Tags: permissions, ossec

We are running OSSEC 3.2 on some Debian servers. We are using OSSEC's `syscheck` to alert us when certain files and directories change.

I want `syscheck` to generate an alert when the directory `/tmp` changes. Now, I don't care about any of `/tmp`'s *content*, but I *do* care about the directory itself. For example, if the permissions on `/tmp` change, or its group or owner changes, I want to know.

How do I tell `syscheck` to alert me on changes to `/tmp` but not to its contents?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below:

```
<directories check_owner="yes" check_group="yes" check_perm="yes">/tmp</directories>
```